# What's the quickest way to store an IPFS hash onto filecoin?

Tags: ipfs, filecoin

I have an IPFS Hash / URL and I'd like to store it on [Filecoin](https://filecoin.io/).

What is the quickest most effective way for me to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ally from Filecoin here :)

The easiest way to use ipfs and Filecoin to ensure censorship-resistance & resiliency is by

- Using [Fleek](https://fleek.co/) (while this does introduce a measure of centralisation, it still creates an immutable IPFS CID and does Filecoin storage deals for you, so all your data is still decentralised). **You could then** back up the resilience of it though by using multiple other services too eg. by adding the below:
- Using an IPFS pinning service (such as pinata) and/or running your own [IPFS node](https://docs.ipfs.tech/install/ipfs-desktop/) (again this does introduce a measure of centralisation unless you store on multiple)
- Using [web3.storage](https://web3.storage/) (or even [nft.storage](https://nft.storage/)) - both of which are free services, which create an immutable CID (will be the same one for the same content) & makes a minimum of 8 x Filecoin deals perpetually for you (ie. permanent storage).
- Using [estuary.tech](https://estuary.tech) - which gives you the option of running your own estuary node also (both pins to ipfs and makes Filecoin storage deals) and is probably the best solution here
- Using [Chainsafe storage sdk](https://files.chainsafe.io/) or other storage helpers like [Lighthouse Storage](https://www.lighthouse.storage/) - which I believe allows you to drop in your own IPFS CID and creates these Filecoin deals for you.

If you DO want to make your own Filecoin storage deals, this is currently, well, hard (bring on [FVM](https://fvm.filecoin.io) perpetual storage contracts & aggregation contracts - this will potentially allow for smart contracts that can make their own deals with the network!). It is possible to make your own deals now though with:

- Snap deals - [Ref](https://lotus.filecoin.io/storage-providers/operate/snap-deals/#:%7E:text=A%20one%2Dmessage%20protocol%20for,having%20to%20seal%20new%20sectors.)
- Other resource for making your own storage deals with Filecoin [here](https://lotus.filecoin.io/tutorials/lotus/store-and-retrieve/store-data/)

Some further resources on deploying decentralised websites:

- [Websites on IPFS](https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/websites-on-ipfs/multipage-website/#project-set-up)
- [Breaking free of the client-server model video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEcLeEXiLXY)